# Selector with mouse and custom right click

Tags: javascript, items

Last time, I wanted to make a little application with draggable elements.

But now, I want to improve my code.

First, please have a look at my plunker project, where i pasted al my code in.
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/gD9Q3NYQES4OMVmY

**What i want to do: Step 1**
What i want to do now, is that you can select 2 or 3 draggable items. How? I want to make that like on some software systems, on which you can select the items with just crop a box over the items and then all selected items get a background (for showing they are selected).

**Now Step 2**

If you click NOT on an item, the custom right-click is just like this: https://prnt.sc/lmh7a6
But if you right click on an item, you should be able to execute some other action like deleting it.
But if you select a couple of items, you should be able to delete them all or something like this.

Thank you guys, for all help :)

Comment: If I saw correctly, last time you posted your own code and asked for what goes wrong.  Here you are simply asking for StackOverflow to expand your project. Please begin with an attempt.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Excuse me, the project is actually a bit too hard for me and my knowledge about javascript. I edited the plnkr project like this, that you can delete items easly. I think, this is just a piece of the work. But i try my best. I try, after this post, again, how i could do this. I don't think, i find a solution, but eventually i can expand my work like this, that anyone shouldn't write all for me.